# Align child view to edge of parent layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have this ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/my_img_1" />
```

It is the child of a `RelativeLayout`. I am expecting the image to appear flushed with the upper-left corner of the `page`/`parent`. But it's not. There is about `20dp` `margin`/`padding` between the parent's left and top and the child view. How do I get what I want?

Comment: Obvious question but... the RelativeLayout has no padding?

Comment: ah! I forgot to take out the automatic `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    `. This is crazy but do you mind reposting as a response?

Comment: There's your answer :) Remove the padding on the parent

Comment: @KenWolf do you mind reposting as a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect is what should happen.

It sounds like the holding `RelativeLayout` has 20dp padding on it - this would lead to the behaviour you describe.

Make sure you've removed the padding from your parent `RelativeLayout`!